# Swift, repeating checkmark

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

```
var rennersArray = […..with 36 names]

var checkersOpFalse = [Bool](repeating: false, count: 36)

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = rennersArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = checkersOpFalse[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {

        checkersOpFalse[indexPath.row] = !(cell.accessoryType == .checkmark)

        cell.accessoryType = checkersOpFalse[indexPath.row] ? .checkmark : .none

        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath) {

            if cell.accessoryType == .checkmark {
                code code
            }
```

Everything works fine.
Now I have the same code with sections in my tableview but now the checkmark repeats.

Someone how to fix this?

Comment: Do not obtain and update a cell in `didSelectRowAt`. Instead, tell the table view to reload that one row after you update your data model.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more please?

Comment: show also the code that does not work.. and explain how does the checkmark repeats

Comment: @MilanNosáľ It's pretty clear. See my answer.

Comment: can you please post the full code? in this snippet it looks like you are calling the cell-for-row method multiple times inside the did-select-row method which would be kinda strange if that happens in real.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite your `didSelectRowAt`. All it should do is update your data model and then reload the row.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    checkersOpFalse[indexPath.row] = !checkersOpFalse[indexPath.row]

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [ indexPath ], with: .fade)
}
```

This puts all of the logic to configure a cell where it belongs - in `cellForRowAt`.

Now your real issue with sectioned data showing wrong checkmarks is due your `checkersOpFalse` being an array based solely on the row of an index path. That clearly doesn't work when you have multiple sections.

You should make `checkersOpFalse` a dictionary keyed on an `IndexPath`.

```
var checkersOpFalse = [IndexPath: Bool]()
```

Then update `didSelectRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    checkersOpFalse[indexPath] = !checkersOpFalse[indexPath, default: false]

    tableView.reloadRows(at: [ indexPath ], with: .fade)
}
```

And `cellForRowAt`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = rennersArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    cell.accessoryType = checkersOpFalse[indexPath, default: false] ? .checkmark : .none

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanx Maddy, try this later.